# Can I use a adsense in Webview based android app?

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I have a website with AdSense ad placements. Now, we have created an Android app using WebView and displayed my website within the app. Additionally, I integrated the WebView API for ads as per the following link:

https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/11893859?hl=en

Link: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/webview

Please let me know if this is allowed according to Google AdSense policy. I hope I can use AdSense in the WebView app?"

Please let me know if this is allowed according to Google AdSense policy. I hope I can use AdSense in the WebView app?"

Comment: That's not really a programming question. You might want to contact the corresponding customer service for such questions. Also -- please don't repeat sentences unnecessarily.

Comment: hi @Krokomot, this was a mistake not added intentionally, hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but the webview must show a website, so your AdSense Ads should be linked to a web domain.

This was prohibited in the past but now it is OK.